# Gridview not showing/hiding toolbar

Tags: android, gridview, android-design-library

I'm using the Design Support Library and I use a `GridView` but when I scroll up or down to the grid the `Toolbar` is not hiding or showing. I use the same code on a `RecyclerView` and it's working just fine.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my *.xml file in my activity. I just `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` and initialize the GridView Adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the `ListView` and the `GridView` have the expected behavior with the `CoordinatorLayout` only with **API>21**.

To obtain this behavior you have to set:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    gridView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696611/design-lib-coordinatorlayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-gridview-listview/30885092#30885092).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you use `CoordinatorLayout` as the parent layout, you need to use a `RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView` to have it working properly

Comment: Try enclosing the GridView in a NestedScrollView. From what users have been reporting so far only RecyclerView and NestedScrollView cooperate properly with the CoordinatorLayout

Comment: The only other solution I can think of is (if possible) to transform your GridView in a RecyclerView implementing a GridLayoutManager