# Design lib - CoordinatorLayout/CollapsingToolbarLayout with GridView/listView

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, coordinator-layout

This might be silly question but I didn't understand Design lib well. I am following [this reference](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml) to create below layout. The Blue area should work as parallax when I scroll the `GridView`.
But when I scroll grid View nothing happens in AppBarLayout.

But This works with `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`

[image: Layout]

Below is My Layout file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#500403"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#122453"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/bar_offline"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#982223"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <GridView
      android:id="@+id/grid"
      android:numColumns="4"
      android:background="#367723"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:src="@drawable/bar_offline"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

With ListView/GridView, it works only on Lollipop by following code-

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
     listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
}
```

I think for Now CoordinatorLayout works only with `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`

### EDIT :

**use -**

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView/gridview,true); (add Android Support v4 Library 23.1 or +)
```

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

A simple solution was added to the support lib:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView,true);
```

I've tested it with  *Android Support v4 Library 23.1* and it works well.

Answer (score 7):

Currently the `ListView` and the `GridView` have the expected behavior with the `CoordinatorLayout` only with API>21.

To obtain this behavior you have to set:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {   
    setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
 }
```

It is not enough to implement the `NestedScrollingChild`.
The `AbsListView` isn't deployed with support libraries , then it depends by the SO running in the device.

You have to override some methods in the AbsListView. For example you can check the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Inside this code you can see:

```
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    //......
    startNestedScroll(SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
    //....
  }

  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    //.....
     if (startScrollIfNeeded((int) ev.getX(pointerIndex), y, null)) {
    //....     
   }
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
          //..
         stopNestedScroll();
            break;
   }
```

This code is only in the implementation of AbsListView v21+.
If you check the AbsListView with *API 20* or lower, you will not find any nested scroll reference.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put gridview inside NestedScrollview as usual then you have to add gridview height dynamically. then everything would work good.!!!

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
               android:fillViewport="true">


               <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:orientation="vertical">

              <GridView
               android:id="@+id/camp_list"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
               android:layout_margin="10dp"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
               android:numColumns="3"
               android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
               android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
               android:visibility="visible" >
           </GridView>



               </LinearLayout>
           </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: '              int height = 250;
                 for (int i = 0; i < mNoteList.size(); i++) {
                 height = height + 250;
                 }
                mGridView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height));
                mAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.txt_line1);
                mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);'

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765

I use GridView inside NestedScrollView

Answer (score 0):

For convenience i've created a subclass with the new ViewCompat solution:

```
public class CoordinatedListView extends ListView {

    public CoordinatedListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CoordinatedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CoordinatedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CoordinatedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(this, true);
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)