# How to hide ActionBar while scrolling ListView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I need to create a GUI with a `ListView` and an `ActionBar` which will hide when scrolling down and when scrolling up it must reappear.

The following guides didn't help me:

- https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/
- https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding the ActionBar on RecyclerView/ListView onScroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559275/hiding-the-actionbar-on-recyclerview-listview-onscroll)

Comment: @KubaSpatny I'm trying to implement but your code doesn't work for me. It isn't a duplicate. The previous post doesn't work

Comment: @KubaSpatny What you linked is wrong, if I extend AppCompatActivity it doesn't allow me to Override methods onScrollStateChanged and  onScroll. If I extend Activity I can't use "getSupportActionBar"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you would like to obtain a list with this behaviour, you should:

- add the design support library with `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`
- Use a `CoordinatorLayout` with a Toolbar where you have to define `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`
- Use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696611/design-lib-coordinatorlayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-gridview-listview/30885092#30885092) `ListView` and the `GridView` have the expected behavior with the `CoordinatorLayout` only with API>21. In this case you have to use `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);`

The [official blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) shows this case:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <! -- Your Scrollable View -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                  ...
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could I change the collapsing speed?

Comment: I think that the only way is to use a custom Behavior

Comment: There is another problem. When the toolbar is hidden and I left the app, open another app, open the app again, the toolbar became without everything, just a rectangle with a color.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour with ListView? with RecyclerView it works fine. But I'm using `ExpandableListView` where I need the same behaviour. Is it possible?

Comment: Currently the `ListView` and the `GridView` have the expected behavior with the `CoordinatorLayout` only with API>21. Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30885092/2016562.

Comment: How do you make this compatible with API 18-21?

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend using the new support design library by Google.

Include it in your dependecies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

and then use the `AppBarLayout` together with `NestedScrollView`.

For your `Toolbar` define `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`, which says it will disappear as you scroll, and come back immediately if you scroll up (meaning you don't have to scroll all the way up).

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @maveň I actually don't think this question is that bad. It may be a duplicate though, but considering the new library I though of giving an easier answer.

Comment: It doesn't work, I can only move the actionbar and the listview is stuck

Comment: @user4789408 there might be a problem in using `ListView` with API lower than 21. Instead use the `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [CoordinatorLayout]:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html, which allow co-oridanation among child views. it's like, act(AppBarLayout->scrolling) on some view when there is a behaviour observed(ListView->scroll) in another view.

1. Make Listview nestedScrollingEnabled, works for >API 21

   ```
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
   ```
2. Trigger layout behaviour to appbar scrolling.

   ```
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   ```
3. Any layout(ToolBar/TabLayout/any), which is required to show-hide/scroll, place it inside AppBarLayout, and enabled scroll flag.

   ```
   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `CoordinatorLayout` for this task. It is part of the support design library. [Here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), in the **CoordinatorLayout and the app bar**  section, you can find an example