# Toolbar doesn't hiding while scrolling

Tags: android, xml

trying to hide toolbar on listview scroll by using appbar_scrolling_view_behavior + scroll flags, but has no result, this is xml code, can't understand what's wrong with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lol.materialdesigntest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/list_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: code looks ok..what os version are you testing?

Comment: This might help you!
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290337/how-to-hide-actionbar-while-scrolling-listview-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ListView doesn't have the nested scrolls enabled by default. Use

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(listView, true);
```

to enable it.

Be aware that this will from from lollipop onwards . If you want to support older versions of android you should use a RecyclerView

Comment: be aware that this will from from lollipop onwards . If you want to support older versions of android you should use a RV

Answer (score 2):

**`ListView` doesn't support nested scrolling**

Use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and enable nested scrolling in `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use `RecyclerView` with  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.